# High resolution on small screen size

Tags: resolution, high-resolution

I have recently got an Intel UltraBook, but its screen size is 13.3" and the native resolution is 1600×900.

So the problem is that the letters on screen are very small. Reducing resolution blurs the display and making everything bigger also doesn't feel very good.

Us there a way to get around this problem without changing hardware?

I'd even be okay with this high resolution, but I am concerned about the harmful effects it might have on my eyes in long term.

Comment: Which version of windows are you running? There is a way to change global text sizes, but it's different in 8 than it was in 7.... Ill post an answer when you reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the text size setting in Windows which will affect all text across dialogs, icons, applications (if they follow MS standards) etc.

In Windows 7 and Windows 8:

1. Right click on your desktop and select `Screen Resolution`
2. Click the `Make text and other items larger or small` link at the bottom
3. Click the `Medium - 125%` radio button
4. Click `Apply`

If this is still too small, try `Larger - 150%`

You can also set a specific DPI instead of one of the three presets.

- In Windows 7, click the `Set custom test size (DPI)` link in the left
  hand menu
- In Windows 8, click the `Custim sizing options` link under the presets list

Then drag the ruler left and right to adjust the size

Additionally, in Windows 8 you have more granular control over specific parts of windows via the `Change the text size only` options

Answer (score 0):

should not harm your eyes, only tiring, what about reading glasses

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a little? Do you have proper resources to backup your claim that it's not harmful?

Comment: it's in german, sorry I don't know interational researches about this.
http://www.ergo-online.de/html/gesundheitsvorsorge/beanspruchungen_erkrankungen/augen1.pdf